# cURL for Mac OS X Lion

Tags: mac, osx-lion, curl

I am looking for cURL for Mac OS X 10.  I have found versions that go up to OS X 8 ([Link](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html)), but no later.  Is there a version for OS X 10 (Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 (11G63)) or another tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

curl is built into Mac OSX now.

Comment: How to I call it from Terminal?

Comment: type "curl" and that should work.